# In rails iterate CSV, log errors but not stop looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to iterate through a malformed CSV like this:

"col1",1000,"col2","malformed "col3", "col4"

"col1",1000,"col2","col3", "col4"

"col1",1000,"col2",""malformed col3, "col4"

using `Rails` so, when an error in a row is found a `CSV::MalformedCSVError` is thrown but loop does not stop.

I looked for different solutions but nothing worked until know . :(

Currently I have a method like this:

```
def iterate_csv
  puts 'lets iterate!!'
  CSV.foreach(@file) { |line| 
    begin
      puts 'loop is on fire...'
      # handle line here
    rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError => e
      puts e
      # handle malformed row here...
    next
    end
  }
end
```

All help I found googling did not help.. any input appreciated!

Comment: In which line is the error thrown exactly? My guess is that `CSV.foreach` raises the error, which is outside of your rescue block. Try to process the file line by line: use `File.foreach` and pass each line to `CSV.parse`. If it can't be parsed, the error will be raised, but you'll continue to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want stop the loop you should put `break`instead of `next`.